# Undefined variable: node in node_links Drupal Panalizer

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Am using **drupal panalizer** for the **content type**. Somehow I could not add node_links field Shown in ajax error. It is an Undefined variable node. How could I fix this issue. For reference

[image]

[image]